# Web Audio filter for visuals and not sound

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

How would I use a filter on the AnalyserNode data without that filter effecting the song that is being played?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, insert your filter before the AnalyserNode, but don't connect the AnalyserNode to anything.  If your original graph had the output of the AnalyserNode feeding other parts, you'll have to reroute the signal so that it goes to where the Analyser used to go.  Be sure to take the signal before the filter, of course.

Comment: I have tried branching it off but the filter still has to chain to the source, doesn't it? Say I have a set up like: Source -> 10 biquads for EQ -> compressor -> whatever else -> Destination. Is it possible to get a branch from the source with a biquad -> analyzer and get the frequency data without this biquad manipulating the audio playing?

Comment: Sure.  Source -> another biquad -> analyser.  Since the biquad only goes to the analyser and not the compressor, its effect doesn't end up in the destination.